# Hidden Markov Model for classification

Tags: hidden-markov-model, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I have fitted a Gaussian mixture model to my data. This Gaussian mixture model is the combination of two Gaussian distributions. I call the first Gaussian distribution state 1 and the second Gaussian distribution state 2. I now want to classify each observations to one of the two states. How could I do this? Do I need the Virterbri algorithm, the Backward-Forward algorithm or some different kind of algorithm?

Comment: Do you have a sequence of observations? Or are each observations independent?

Comment: Yes, I have a sequence of stock returns, which I wish to classify as bull/bear market.   They are of course independent between each other, but depend on one of the two mixtures.